# Create multiple onFinalize triggers for the buckets in the same project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've created a project in Firebase Storage with multiple buckets, something like this:

```
Project Storage:
 Bucket1
  File
  File
 Bucket2
  File
 Bucket3
  File
  File
```

I want to have something like this:

```
exports.fun = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(){} for bucket1
exports.fun = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(){} for bucket3
```

Is this possible?
And how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) is pretty clear:

> Use `functions.storage` to create a function that handles Cloud Storage
>   events. Depending on whether you want to scope your function to a
>   specific Cloud Storage bucket or use the default bucket, use one of
>   the following:
>
> - `functions.storage.object()` to listen for object changes on the default storage bucket.
> - `functions.storage.bucket('bucketName').object()` to listen for object changes on a specific bucket.

You can use the second form to specify the bucket.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I did something wrong with my bucket name and that's why it wasn't working :/